# Issue while populating JSON data to Jquery datatable in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

I'm using coldFusion 2016 and I'm facing one issue when I'm putting json data to my Jquery datatable. The datatable is only showing processing message.
The JSON result seems to be error free but i don't know what is the issue.

Here is my datatable implementation

```html
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript">
var table = '';
$(document).ready(function() {
   table = $('#example').DataTable( {
     "bProcessing": true,
       "bServerSide": true,
     "ajax": "uploadProcess.cfc?method=getDetails&partyId=100004",
  "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
  "oLanguage": {
     "sProcessing":   "Wait please...",
     "sZeroRecords":  "No records found.",
     "sInfo":         "Users from _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ total",
        "sInfoEmpty":    "Users from 0 to 0 of 0 total"
    },
  "aoColumns": [
                        { "data": "ID" },
                        { "data": "ORG_NAME" },
                        { "data": "TYPE" },
                        { "data": "PATH" },
                        { "data": "URL" },
                        { "data": "DELETE" }
                     ]
    });
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dataDiv">
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>File Name</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Path</th>
            <th>Preview</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
 </div>
</body>
```

Here is my uploadProcess.cfc

```html
<cfcomponent>
<cffunction name="getDetails" access="remote" returnFormat="json">
 <cfargument name="partyId" type="string" required="yes">
 <cfparam name="arguments.iDisplayStart" default="0">
 <cfparam name="arguments.iDisplayLength" default="10">
 <cfparam name="arguments.iSortCol_0" default="UploadFileID">
 <cfparam name="arguments.sSortDir_0" default="ASC">
 <cfparam name="arguments.sEcho" default="1">
 
 <cfstoredproc procedure="get_upload_file_details" datasource="standout">
 <cfprocparam value="#partyId#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INT">
 <cfprocparam value="#arguments.iDisplayStart#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INT">
 <cfprocparam value="#arguments.iDisplayLength#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INT">
 <cfprocparam value="#arguments.iSortCol_0#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">
 <cfprocparam value="#arguments.sSortDir_0#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">
 <cfprocresult name="getUploadDtls">
 </cfstoredproc>

 <cfset userArray = arrayNew(1)> 
 
 <cfloop query="getUploadDtls">
 <cfif UserSessionID eq "">
    <cfset deleteLink = "<span class='delete-link link'>Delete</span>" />
    <cfelse>
    <cfset deleteLink = "">
    </cfif>
  <cfset userStruct = {}>
  <cfset userStruct.ID = UploadFileID>
  <cfset userStruct.ORG_NAME = OriginalFileName>
  <cfset userStruct.GEN_NAME = SystemFileName>
  <cfset userStruct.TYPE = DocumentName>
  <cfset userStruct.PATH = FilePath>
  <cfset userStruct.URL = "<a href='renderpdf.cfm?path=#FilePath#&name=#OriginalFileName#' target='_blank'>Preview</a>">
  <cfset userStruct.DELETE = deleteLink>  
  <cfset arrayAppend(userArray, userStruct) >
 </cfloop>
  <cfif getUploadDtls.RecordCount GT 0>
     <cfset firstRow = queryGetRow(getUploadDtls,1)>
  <cfset record_count = firstRow.record_count>
  <cfelse>
  <cfset record_count = 0>
     </cfif>
 <cfset returnStruct = {}>
 <cfset returnStruct['iTotalRecords'] = record_count>
 <cfset returnStruct['iTotalDisplayRecords'] = record_count>
 <cfset returnStruct['sEcho'] = arguments.sEcho>
 <cfset returnStruct['aaData'] = userArray>
 <cfset resultsJSON = SerializeJSON(returnStruct)>
 <cfreturn resultsJSON>
</cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

The Json result returning from my cffunction is given below.

```html
{""aaData"":[{""GEN_NAME"":""sample_489.pdf"",""PATH"":""C://Standout/web_uploads/100004/Medical Reports/sample_489.pdf"",""DELETE"":"""",""ORG_NAME"":""sample.pdf"",""ID"":77,""TYPE"":""Medical Report"",""URL"":""<a href='renderpdf.cfm?path=C://Standout/web_uploads/100004/Medical Reports/sample_489.pdf&name=sample.pdf' target='_blank'>Preview</a>""}],""iTotalDisplayRecords"":1,""iTotalRecords"":1,""sEcho"":1}"
```

I can't figure out what is the issue can someone help?

Comment: The issue is with your JSON return it's invalid. Try validating your JSON at https://jsonlint.com your json should be like {
 "aaData": [{
  "GEN_NAME": "sample_489.pdf",
  "PATH": "C://Standout/web_uploads/100004/Medical Reports/sample_489.pdf",
  "DELETE": "",
  "ORG_NAME": "sample.pdf",
  "ID": 77,
  "TYPE": "Medical Report",
  "URL": "<a href='renderpdf.cfm?path=C://Standout/web_uploads/100004/Medical Reports/sample_489.pdf&name=sample.pdf' target='_blank'>Preview</a>"
 }],
 "iTotalDisplayRecords": 1,
 "iTotalRecords": 1,
 "sEcho": 1
}

Comment: I already given returnFormat="json" in my cffunction, so the json reached in the front-end will be in correct format as you specified.

Answer (score 0):

First of I would remove those curly braces you use wrapping your structs.
SerializeJson() already works pretty well if you just pass in your structs.

It seems like your JSON is not valid which is probably causing the error, or your datatable isn't configured properly.

Honestly I'd recommend just filling your table with a cfloop.

```
<cfloop query="myQuery">
   <tr>
       <td>
          #myQuery.someData#
       </td>
       ...
   </tr>
</cfloop>
```

If you load your data on page load this solution might work just as well.
The datatable API can be hit or miss sometimes imo.